# Blind STBC question

Tags: matlab, signal-analysis, digital-communications, signal-detection, mimo

[image]I am working on blind identification of the physical layer parameters of a particular protocol. Everything was going well until I got to the MIMO part. The system contains two transmitter antennas and two receiver antennas. I found that the WiMAX standard was very similar to the protocol I was considering, so I began to adapt different WiMAX space-time coding methods to the existing protocol data. What I understand is that spatial multiplexing is not used, because I can send and receive even with a transmitter antenna.

It seems that the only option is space-time coding. I saw that the relationship of Alamouti is established in many cases, but in some places it is not established. However there are similarities with Alamouti even in places where it is not established . I discovered four modes:

The first mode is Alamouti (figure (a)).

The second mode is Alamouti, with reversed numbering of antennas (figure (b)).

The third mode is that the second time slot symbol of each antenna is the complex conjugate of the first time slot symbol of another antenna (figure (c)).

And the fourth case is that the second time slot symbol of each antenna is a negative complex conjugate of the first time slot symbol of another antenna (figure (d)).

Is it possible that the space-time coding used is something other than Alamouti? Has something like this happened somewhere? May it be related to the concept of group decodable STBC?